# Pandas: Max or min function according to another column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
| Date       | Word    | Numb |
|------------|---------|------|
| 2020/01/01 | ab      | 12   |
| 2020/01/01 | bc      | 24   |
| 2020/01/01 | ab      | -12  |
| 2020/01/01 | bc      | 34   |
| 2020/01/02 | ab      |  3   |
| 2020/01/02 | bc      | 123  |
| 2020/01/02 | ab      | -8   |
| 2020/01/02 | bc      | 12   |
```

I would like to create a new dataframe where I get the min value in the column Numb if the string in the column Word is **ab** and the max value if the string is **bc** for each Date. For example, the result with the above dataframe should be:

```
|            |      | Numb |
| Date       | Word |      |
|------------|------|------|
| 2020/01/01 | ab   | -12  |
|            | bc   | 34   |
| 2020/01/02 | ab   | -8   |
|            | bc   | 123  |
```

I am using the following groupby function,but it only produce a dataframe with the min value in all the cases:

```
ans=df.groupby(['Date','Element']).min()
```

Comment: Well written first question, input, output and what you tried!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can chain with `groupby` and pass the result to `np.where`

```
s=df.groupby(['Date','Word']).Numb.agg(['min','max'])
s['number']=np.where(s.index.get_level_values(1)=='ab',s.min(1),s.max(1))
s
Out[38]: 
                 min  max  number
Date       Word                  
2020/01/01 ab    -12   12     -12
           bc     24   34      34
2020/01/02 ab     -8    3      -8
           bc     12  123     123
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `pd.concat` with each selected dataframe with the Word, then use `sort_values` once ascending True (to get the min first) and once False (to get the max first), then `drop_duplicates` and keep the first.

```
res = (pd.concat([df[df['Word'].eq('ab')].sort_values('Numb', ascending=True), 
                  df[df['Word'].eq('bc')].sort_values('Numb', ascending=False)])
         .drop_duplicates(['Date','Word'], keep='first')
      )
print(res)
         Date Word  Numb
2  2020/01/01   ab   -12
6  2020/01/02   ab    -8
5  2020/01/02   bc   123
3  2020/01/01   bc    34
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC,

```
groups = df.groupby(['Date','Word'], as_index=False)['Numb']
new_df = groups.min().where(lambda x: x['Word'].eq('ab'), groups.max())
print(new_df)

# s = new_df.set_index(['Date','Word']) #for expected output
```

**Output**

```
         Date Word  Numb
0  2020/01/01   ab   -12
1  2020/01/01   bc    34
2  2020/01/02   ab    -8
3  2020/01/02   bc   123
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do some fancy reshaping, grouping and reshaping again:

```
dfs = df.set_index(['Date','Word'], append=True)['Numb'].unstack()
dfg = dfs.groupby('Date').agg(ab=('ab','min'), bc=('bc','max'))
dfg.stack().to_frame(name='Numb').rename_axis(['Date', 'Word'])
```

Output:

```
                   Numb
Date        Word       
2020/01/01  ab    -12.0
            bc     34.0
2020/01/02  ab     -8.0
            bc    123.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could stack the results after the aggregation :

```
df.groupby("Date").agg(["min", "max"]).stack().droplevel(-1)

         Word   Numb
Date        
2020/01/01  ab  -12
2020/01/01  bc  34
2020/01/02  ab  -8
2020/01/02  bc  123
```